# Get raw string from Rss20FeedFormatter for RSS/XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing, rss, syndication-feed

I am trying to get the raw string of the RSS xml. I tried the below but my string builder ends up blank. What is the correct way to do this?

```
var rssFormatter = new Rss20FeedFormatter(feed, false);
var output = new StringBuilder();
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
{
    rssFormatter.WriteTo(writer);
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to flush your writer...

```
var rssFormatter = new Rss20FeedFormatter(feed, false);
var output = new StringBuilder();
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
{
    rssFormatter.WriteTo(writer);
    writer.Flush();
    return output;
}
```